# Store more character than the assign column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I do something like this, column is of type `nchar(8)`, but the string I wanted to store in the table is longer than that.

The reason I am doing this is because I want to convert from one table to another table. Table A is `nchar(8)` and Table B is `nvarchar(100)`. I want all characters in Table B transfer to Table A without missing any single character.

Comment: Hint:  `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Do you want several rows if the source string is longer than 8 chars?

Comment: This is just as possible as putting 2 liters of water in a 1 liter bottle.

Comment: No - you cannot store more than 8 characters in a varchar(8) (or char, nchar, nvarchar) datatype.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I cannot Alter Table since Table A is been used in many place. Altering the table might break the existing code.

Comment: @HoneyBadger yeah its imposible I guess. but I just looking if there is alternative for this

Comment: @SMor is there any alternative I can do

Comment: @jarlh I not sure what you mean by several row but Its something like table B has more than 8 character and want to transfer to table A which limited to 8 character

Comment: I think what jarlh means is, if the string is longer than 8 characters, do you want the string split over multiple rows?

Comment: Or a wacky alternative might be to create a new table for the 100 characters with a foreign key back to the main table.  (I.e., 2 columns, id, and longvalue)

Answer (score 0):

If the nvarchar(100) contains only latin characters with a length up to 16 chars, then you can squeeze the nvarchar(100) into the nchar(8):

```
declare @t table
(
col100 nvarchar(100),
col8 nchar(8)
);

insert into @t(col100) values('1234567890123456');

update @t
set col8 = cast(cast(col100 as varchar(100)) as varbinary(100))

select *, cast(cast(cast(col8 as varbinary(100)) as varchar(100)) as nvarchar(100)) as from8to100_16charsmax
from @t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify `A`, then you cannot use it to store the data.  Create another table for the overflow . . . something like:

```
create table a_overflow (
    a_pk int primary key references a(pk),
    column nvarchar(max)    -- why stop at 100?
);
```

Then, you can construct a view to bring in the data from this table when viewing `a`:

```
create view vw_a as
    select . . . ,   -- all the other columns
           coalesce(ao.column, a.column) as column
    from a left join
         a_overflow ao
         on ao.a_pk = a.pk;
```

And, if you really want to "hide" the view, you can create an `insert` trigger on `vw_a`, which inserts the appropriate values into the two tables.

This is a lot of work.  Simply modifying the table is much simpler.  That said, this approach is sometimes needed when you need to modify a large table and altering a column would incur too much locking overhead.